# Redirection to the current page Django

Tags: python, redirect

I'm trying to create a login form in Django but I can't find how to fix such a bug. I have a form and the view with redirect in return but the problem is that the form redirects me to the current page even though I defined the path of redirection. Maybe you have some ideas? I tried to google it but it didn't work.
Here is my views.py:

```
def login(request):
    if request.POST.get('submit') == 'sign_in':
        form = login_form(data=request.POST)
        pdb.set_trace()
        return redirect('/account')
        #if form.is_valid():

         #   return HttpResponseRedirect('/account')

    elif request.POST.get('submit') == 'sign_up':
        form = register_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/account')
    else:
        sign_in = login_form()
        sign_up = register_form()
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'login_form':sign_in, 'signup_form': sign_up})

def account(request):
    return HttpResponse('Account')
```

and my login.html:

```
<div class="form-holder">
        <form class="login-form" method="post" style="display: block;">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ login_form }}
            <!--{% for field in login_form %}-->
                <!--<div class="form-group">-->
                    <!--{{ login_form.errors }}-->
                    <!--{{ login_form.label_tag }}-->
                    <!--<br>-->
                    <!--&lt;!&ndash;{{ field }}&ndash;&gt;-->
                    <!--<input class="form-control" id="{{ field.id_for_label }}"-->
                           <!--placeholder="Enter {{ field.html_name }}" name="{{ field.html_name }}" >-->
                    <!--{% if field.help_text %}-->
                    <!--<p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>-->
                    <!--{% endif %}-->
                <!--</div>-->
            <!--{% endfor %}-->
            <!--<div class="form-group">-->
                <!--<label for="email">Email:</label>-->
                <!--<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">-->
            <!--</div>-->
            <!--<div class="form-group">-->
                <!--<label for="pwd">Password:</label>-->
                <!--<input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">-->
            <!--</div>-->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <button type="submit" value="sign_in" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the redirect call currently sending you to?

Comment: It just refreshes the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't check 'action' attribute of my forms. So, `<form class="login-form" method="post" action="/account" style="display: block;">` worked for me and my view redirect me the `/account` page correctly.